Rotating an extruded shape with "filled holes" in Three.JS
I am pretty new to Three.js, so please forgive me if I a missing something obvious here.
My problem setting is the following: I have a 2D shape (e.g. a rectangle) with some holes in it:
 const shape = new THREE.Shape();
 shape.moveTo(...);
 shape.lineTo(...);
 // ...

 const hole = new THREE.Shape();
 hole..moveTo(...);
 hole.lineTo(...);
 // ...

 shape.holes.push(new THREE.Path(hole.getPoints()));

I then extrude this shape into 3D as follows:
const height = ...;
const extrudeSettings = { depth: height };
const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrudeSettings);

This geometry is then rotated by some angle around some axis:
const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(angle, axis);
geometry.applyQuaternion(quaternion);

Finally, the geometry is rendered (using react-three-fiber):
<>
 <mesh geometry={geometry}>
    <meshBasicMaterial
        color={red}
        side={THREE.FrontSide}
     />
 </mesh>
</>

I would now like to fill the holes in this geometry with a (or several) different colors.
My approach until now was to create geometries for the holes by extruding the underlying 2D shape for each hole, applying the same rotation and then rendering them like the "main shape" above. However, I was never able to get them to line up with the holes in the original shape.
It is very likely that my math is just off. However, if anyone knows of a simpler path to achive this / has already done this, I'd be grateful for any insight you have.

I managed to figure it out myself. Turns out three.js provides a group concept which can be used perfectly for this. By just wrapping the main shape and the shapes I want to render in its holes into a group and applying all necessary transformation to that group instead, I was able to transform them in sync.
My code looks similar to this:
<group position={position}>
  <group rotation={rotation}>
    // Render main shape
    <mesh geometry={geometry}>
      <meshBasicMaterial
        color="red"
        side={THREE.FrontSide}
      />
    </mesh>
    // Render holes
    {holeGeometries.map(geometry =>
      <mesh geometry={geometry}>
        <meshBasicMaterial
          color="green"
          side={THREE.FrontSide}
        />
      </mesh>
     )}
  </group>
</group>

